# Homework ,, Probability Axioms .

Tags: probability

If A and B are two events associated with an experiment and P(A) = 0.4 , P(B) = x , and P(A U B) = 0.7 ;
Find : The choice of (x) for which A and B are Mutually Exclusive .

P(A) --> is the Probability of (A) .

(AUB) --> is (A) Union (B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two events are mutually exclusive if they cannot occur at the same time. Formally said, the intersection of each two of them is empty (the null event): $A ∩ B = \emptyset$. In consequence, mutually exclusive events have the property $P(A ∩ B) = 0$.

Using $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ and putting $P(A\cap B)=0$ we find
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)\quad\Rightarrow\quad P(B)=x=P(A\cup B)-P(A)=0.7-0.4=0.3
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the following equality

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: You mean $0.4+0.7-0.4\times0.7=0.82$